# PuTTY telnet password always incorrect on first try

Tags: putty, telnet

Does anyone know why this happens **every single time**? Is it a bug with PuTTY maybe? can't find anything about it on Google

[image]

Comment: What version of putty are you using?  Without it it is hard to tell.

Comment: Release 0.70, 64bit Windows platform :)

Comment: Great.  Now where are you trying to connect?  Server, PC, modem, switch, etc.?

Comment: On a linux server, with Debian9. I tried hitting backspace in case there were invisible characters already in there but it didn't do anything

Comment: I recommend running `wireshark` on the server or client to see what is actually sent the first time when you enter the passwd.

Comment: Let us know how it goes.  I'm quite interested what is sent the first time around.  I don't have any VM with Debian9 to test so I'll wait for your results.